# Garbage value while scanning with getchar() in c

Tags: c, getchar

I am trying to scan a large number digit-by-digit and store into an array and then print it.

But I am struck since morning, and couldn't find the stupid mistake I am doing.

Here is the code :

```
int a[1000000];

int main()
{
    //t is number of test cases
    int t,i=0,n;
    char c;
    scanf("%d\n",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        while((c=getchar())!='\n')
        {
            scanf("%c",&c);
            printf("scanned\n");
            a[i]=c-48;
            i++;
        }
        n=i-1;

        for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i=0;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `getchar` and `scanf` expects to read read a character. So you need to put in every digit *twice*. Also, you should check that the input really *is* a digit (`isdigit`), and use the literal `'0'` instead of the magic number `48`.

Comment: why you ``scanf("%c",&c);`` when you already ``c=getchar()``

Comment: @Krypton : I just missed that line. That's by mistake there. I didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: When fixing this, *check your inputs for validation*.

Comment: You provided the code. That's good. What's missing is a) input, b) observed behaviour, c) expected behaviour. That was easy to guess *this* time, but should be part and parcel of every bug report / support request.

Comment: Running this under your friendly local debugger might have found the problem quite quickly ?  Printing out the digit value would have shown it scanning every other digit !  When `getchar()` returns `-1` things are going to get interesting (briefly) -- sooner or later the last number will end at EOF !  This comes under the general heading: "never trust the input" (as noted elsewhere as well)... always verify... even if all you do is crash out (preferably saying why !) rather than (silently) continuing with broken data.

Answer (score 2):

**Several problems here:**

1. You must verify that `t` has been properly initialized to a non-negative value.
2. You are reading user input **twice** - first with `getchar()` and then with `scanf()`.
3. You are not verifying that the scanned character is a decimal digit between `0` and `9`.
4. You are relying on `48` being the ASCII code for the digit `0`, which is not always the case.

---

**Here is the suggested fix:**

```
int t,n,i;
char c;

t = 0;
scanf("%d\n",&t);

for (n=0; n<t; n++)
{
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if (!('0' <= c && c <= '9'))
        break;
    printf("scanned\n");
    a[n] = c-'0';
}

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program have some fix's, that need to corrected.

1. Don't use `\n` in `scanf` -->  scanf("%d\n",&t);
2. Don't use `getchar()` and `scanf` at the same time. because both will wait for user input.
   `while((c=getchar())!='\n')
   {
       scanf("%c",&c);`
3. while scanning data using `%c` in loops you need to give one space before `%c`.

   `scanf(" %c",&c);`
4. After scanning all the inputs from the user, then print it.
   Try the following changes-

> int a[1000000];

```
int main()
{
    //t is number of test cases
    int t,i=0,n;
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&t); // Fix 1
    while(t--)
    { // Fix 2
            scanf(" %c",&c); Fix 3
            printf("scanned\n");
            a[i]= c - 48;
            i++;
    }
    n=i-1; </pre>
    // Fix 4
        for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i=0;        
    }
```